# Is it possible to redirect files in a readonly filesystem?

Tags: linux, hardening

Let's assume that I have created a linux image with a filesystem that is inherently readonly (like SquashFS) and disabled swap. From readonly I mean the main filesystem and all its content is readonly and it is mounted readonly as well, and only directories that need to be writable such as `/tmp` is redirected to another writable storage/partition.

Now my question is that if someone has a full root access on this system, is it possible that he somehow spoof accessing files in readonly part or not? For example, if `a.so` is in readonly part, is it possible that all access to this file is redirected to another file? He can copy any file on the writable section of system or run them with root permission.

Best Regards

Comment: How about I bypass your requirement all together with `mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdX /`  Now the whole thing is writable again, and can be modified anyway.  This is exactly what every LiveCD does where the file system is `squashFS`  The filesystem gets "unsquashed" and expanded as read-write every time it's mounted by the Live System.  What security measure are you trying to implement where you don't want user modifications? Disabling `swap` is moot as Linux will operate without it.  Swapspace only increases efficiency when RAM is full.

Comment: @eyoung100 I have a small device which people have a root access to it, but I want to make sure they cannot tamper with the device. I think I have tried to remount device but result was still readonly. I thought that because squashFS is a readonly filesystem, even after remounting and I will not be able to write into it.

Comment: It is a read only file system, but see [WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SquashFS).  When unsquaashed or mated with a writable file system the read-only aspect can be circumvented. Why can you not put all the users in one group and remove their root access??

Comment: `mount --bind` is one of many ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your scenario, where the main filesystem is mounted as read-only and only specific directories like `/tmp` are writable, the short answer is yes, someone with root access could potentially redirect access from files in the read-only part of the system to another file in the writable section. Here's how:

Symbolic or Hard Links: A root user could create symbolic links (symlinks) to redirect access from the original file to a new file in a writable area. Although creating a symlink in the read-only filesystem itself wouldn't be possible, the user could place the symlink in a writable area and adjust the environment (e.g., `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for libraries) or application configurations to use the symlink instead of the original file.

LD_PRELOAD Trick: For shared libraries like your example of `a.so`, a root user could exploit the `LD_PRELOAD` feature of the dynamic linker. This feature allows specifying custom shared libraries to be loaded before others. The user could copy `a.so` to a writable area, modify it as desired, and then use LD_PRELOAD to load their modified version instead of the original, effectively redirecting the access.

Manipulating the Environment: Beyond file manipulation, a root user could also change environment variables or use chroot environments to alter the way applications run, redirecting them to use different files or configurations stored in writable areas.

Mount --bind Option: The `mount --bind` option can be used to mount a directory or file from one part of the file system over another. A root user could use this to overlay a writable directory or file over a location in the read-only part, effectively redirecting access to the writable version.

It's important to note that while these methods can redirect access from read-only to writable parts of the system, they require root access to execute. This highlights the importance of securing root access on your system. If a user has unrestricted root access, the integrity of the system can be compromised in numerous ways, not just file redirection. Ensuring that only trusted users have root access and employing additional security measures (like SELinux or AppArmor) can help mitigate these risks.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. As a last resort, someone with root access could always just load a kernel module or modify code such that it makes the kernel behave in whatever way they want.

More easily, the Linux Kernel already brings overlayfs for exactly the purpose you describe. So, this is rather common usage and just a question of configuration of the overlay.